# AWS AWSiOSSDKv2 DynamoDB Error

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

This has been working fine for over a year and then:

Error occurred: [Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x61000004c300 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=832912, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=0}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=0, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=832912, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found.}]

Is Amazon just down today? The "healthy" status shows that it is up.

Comment: what version of the sdk are you using?

Comment: This has been resolved. It was a VPN issue and not an issue with AWS.